# How to add class if date is more a defined date on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let say I want to let users know if after a defined date. Probably adding a class to style something.
It has to be on page load showing right away. 
Appreciate any help out there.

Comment: you want to show some html after some date passed ?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read through the [help], in particular [_How do I ask a good question?_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Do your [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/6634591), [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

using this the div will only show after `December 17, 2019 03:24:00`

## using css visibility

```js
if (new Date() > new Date("December 17, 2019 03:24:00")) {
  document.getElementById("after").style.visibility = "visible";
} else {
  document.getElementById("before").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

```html
<div id="after" style="visibility: hidden;">not shown until December 17, 2019 03:24:00</div>
<div id="before" style="visibility: hidden;">shown until December 17, 2019 03:24:00</div>
```

## or using css display to not insert a blank when div is hidden

```js
if (new Date() > new Date("December 17, 2019 03:24:00")) {
  document.getElementById("after").style.display = "block";
} else {
  document.getElementById("before").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div id="after" style="display:none;">not shown until December 17, 2019 03:24:00</div>
<div id="before" style="display:none;">shown until December 17, 2019 03:24:00</div>
```

---

using pure JS but I know JQuery has a `hide` function but I don't know how to use it

Comment: Inviting edits to modify your code is not generally a good idea.  Edits that modify code would typically be considered invalid (unless it was simply to fix a typo or similar), as it would be considered changing your answer, which is not permitted.

Comment: @cale_b didn't see it like that but now that you say it it is logical, will remove that